# Calculating Subnets

Tags: networking, subnet

I have just set up my first home LAN, and I want to start playing around with some basic networking concepts. Specifically, I would like to create two subnets. Now although I want these subnets to be meaninful and to serve a real function, I want them more so as to get practice setting up my first subnets.

Since I'm really new to networking, the only use I can think of for subnets on a home LAN might be to have a range of "public" IP addresses that can be reached from outside my private home LAN, and a range of IPs that would be "private" (internal/intranet).

I was thinking that if I gave my network a netmask of `255.255.255.128`, that it would split all available IP's into 2 groups: a "public" range in between `192.168.1.[0,127]` and a "private" range between `192.168.1.[129,255]`.

Have my assumptions thus far been correct? If not, please correct me and steer me in the right direction (perhaps my netmask is wrong?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are mostly correct – using 255.255.255.128 would result in two ranges of 128 addresses, 0-127 (network 192.168.1.0/25) and 12**8**-255 (network 192.168.1.128/25).

However, as long as the network is in the 192.168.0.0/16 range, it *will not* be reachable from outside your LAN; according to [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) this range is reserved for private networks and will not be routed over the public Internet. (Even if it were, *which* of the millions of LANs with identical private addresses would the packets go to?)